# Set element height till end of view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, height, android-mapview

Guys I have the code above which looks like this:

[image: example]

The issue is that I need to set the height hardcoded in order to make it visible.
What I want is to set the height till the bottom of my mainview.

Is this possible using the height attribute or do I need to use other attributes?
My current implementation looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".pkgFragment.LocationAddFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLayoutAddLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/abLayoutAddLocation"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="1"
                >
            
                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/vehicle_name"/>
                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/vehicle_name"/>
            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/llLayoutAddLocation"

            >

        </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You can't simultaneously set the height as hardcoded and make it fill the remaining space.  Match_parent height will make it fill the remainder.  WHy do you think it needs to be hardcoded?

Comment: @GabeSechan i dont want it be hardcoded but mit matchparent, the view also covers the linearlayout thats why I tried it setting it hardcoded which is bad practise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I MapView's height/width doesn't need to be **hardcoded**. I checked the repo myself. You can use match_parent to fill up the whole bottom area. Here is the sample from the repo [MapView Sample Layout](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/GoogleWrapperSample/src/main/res/layout/map_with_locationbox.xml) .

I suggest, Instead of `RelativeLayout`, use `LinearLayout` as the child(only) of `ScrollView` and set the `MapView` Height to `match_parent`.

Your code will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLayoutAddLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="1"
                >
            
                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/vehicle_name"/>
                <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/vehicle_name"/>
            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Edit:
I've edited the answer. Remove the scrollview and set the height and width of the Parent LinearLayout to match_parent.

Comment: I tried ur code out but my map is not filled till end of the screen unfourtantly.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check.

Comment: it works. however I found a bug in the code: When the phone is rotated and I have lets say a textview with open keyboard the keyboard dissapears. thats why I did put scrollview in the first case. In order to keep the keyboard in case I ever add a textview. But for now this solution will work also I guess :)

Comment: Good to hear it's working.